# SharePoint 2010 offers to save Pdf documents instead of opening in the browser

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-2010

We just migrated my sites from 2007 to 2010. Now SharePoint 2010 offers to save Pdf document when clicking on the document in the document library. MOSS2007 was showing Pdf documents in the browser.

I have checked other posts and Web Application has Browser File Handling set to "Permissive". Please advise what else I can do.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible causes:

1. First of all you may have
   BrowserFileHandling set to "Strict"
   on the list level. According to
   MSDN, list level property
   BrowserFileHanlding is an override
   setting.
2. Please check that your Document
       Library settings are set to display
       document in the browser. Sometimes,
       option can be set to display in the
       client first.

If you nothing helps, check my recent blog at https://www.pdfsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-and-pdf-integration-series-part-1/   There is solution #2 (PowerShell) that allows you to add Pdf MIME type to AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes. This option does not require "Permissive" BrowserFileHandling at all. Also you can limit files that can be opened in browse to Pdf file types only.

If even "AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes" does not help, then there is some issue on the client side. Check your Adobe Acrobat/Reader settings to ensure that nothing was changed since your upgrade to SharePoint 2010.

Thanks,
Dmitry